# Access - Get the total of a column in a select query

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an Access database set up that takes a bunch of raw data, splits things up in different 'select' queries and pipes the results into various CSV files, where a dashboard set up in Excel will pick it up.

There's some data that I'm trying to calculate in Access, namely I have a quantity field, and I need to calculate the percentage of for each record. In other words, quantity / total of quantity.

Using my rather limited Access abilities, I tried the following query:

```
SELECT [Sales].*, [Quantity] / Sum([Quantity]) AS QuantityPercent FROM [Sales];
```

Which comes up with an error:

```
Your query does not include the specified expression 'company_name' as part of an aggregate function.
```

Company_name is the first field of the table, and after some Googling and Binging, I'm still quite confused as to what it means in this context.

To sum it up, my question is this: Is there a way to calculate data based off the total of a column/field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy method is to use `DSum`:

```
SELECT 
    [Sales].*, 
    [Quantity] / DSum("[Quantity]", "[Sales]") AS QuantityPercent
FROM 
    [Sales];
```